# v4l2 kernel space debugging

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, v4l2

Is there any default mechanism to enable debugging the v4l2 drivers.
Basically I want to check something like dynamic debugging by setting in /d.
Compile time flags in make file also fine.

Currently, I had set as below, however not getting much information.

```
echo -n 0xFFFF>/sys/module/videobuf2_core/parameters/debug
```

Can anybody help me to get verbose v4l2 logs?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look in the code: As an example the file 
**drivers/media/v4l2-core/v4l2-ioctl.c**
might be one of the more interesting ones, cause it shows you some of the user/kernel-space interactions.

In this file you see a lot of **pr_cont**, **pr_info** and others. While **printk** is always printed, the others only do something, if enabled. All details on this can be found on http://lwn.net/Articles/487437/ .

The nasty way is to just replace some of the pr_cont or pr_info by printk. You can even use a #define to do this. If you only want to enable 3 or 4 of them and even add your own special ones, this might be the fastest way.

The nice way would be to have a look on how the system is thought to be used. You can try if you can enable dynamic debugging, like it is nicely described here https://lwn.net/Articles/434833/ .

Finally the easiest way might be to have a look in the kernel config. Perhaps you already know the command *make menuconfig* in the source directory.
You can edit all the different settings, and like in vi, you can search using /.
Next to the specific modules, you can usually also enable or disable debugging options.
If that's not enough, you can always change the global debugging level of the kernel in the .config file.

One specific flag you might be interested in is

```
CONFIG_VIDEO_ADV_DEBUG
Say Y here to enable advanced debugging functionality on some
V4L devices.
In doubt, say N.

Symbol: VIDEO_ADV_DEBUG [=y]
Prompt: Enable advanced debug functionality on V4L2 drivers
  Location:
    -> Device Drivers
      -> Multimedia support (MEDIA_SUPPORT [=y]) 
  Defined at drivers/media/v4l2-core/Kconfig:11
  Depends on: MEDIA_SUPPORT [=y]
```

good luck

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the official documentation [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/media/kapi/v4l2-dev.html):

> The ‘dev_debug’ attribute that is created for each video, vbi, radio
> or swradio device in /sys/class/video4linux// allows you to
> enable logging of file operations.

I tested this on real configuration and it works(it prints all info!), see my command below:

```
echo 0x1f > /sys/class/video4linux/video1/dev_debug
```